# On some window width make 4 unlisted list (ul) in to one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have page on my site with events. Because all 'li' are not in same dimension I put them in four 'ul' and floated them left.

```
.DogadjajiLista{
    width:225px;
    margin-right:15px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
.DogadjajiLista li{
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    width:225px;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    overflow:visible;
    float:left;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #cecece;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #cecece;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #cecece;
}
```

For responsive design I put them in display inline-block.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .DogadjajiLista{
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .DogadjajiLista li{
        display:inline-block;
        padding:0;
        margin:10px 5px; 
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Put my problem is when I have 3 'li' on smaller screen got to align them 2 'li' in row, then one 'li' in row. And after that secon 'ul' with same behaviour, so it doesent look pretty nice. So i wonder if is there some way in javascript or jquery to make four 'ul' into the one on smaller devices. I hope I explained well my problem.
Here You can se in responsinator.
http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.anaizadar.com%2Fhr%2Fdogadjanja

Here is html

```
<ul class="DogadjajiLista">
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika1 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj01.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj1_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj1_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>24.10.-27.10.2013.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika1 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj05.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj5_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj5_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>29.08.-31.08.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika1 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj09.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj9_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj9_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>29.08.-31.08.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
</ul>   
<ul class="DogadjajiLista">
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika1 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj02.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj2_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj2_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>12.06.-15.06.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika2 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj06.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj6_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj6_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>08.08.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika2 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj10.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj10_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj10_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>30.06-04.08.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
</ul>  
<ul class="DogadjajiLista">
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika2 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj03.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj3_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj3_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>06.06.-08.06.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika3 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj07.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj7_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj7_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>10.08.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika3 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj11.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj11_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj11_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>10.08.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
</ul>  
<ul class="DogadjajiLista">
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika3 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj04.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj4_naslov?></h2>
            <p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj4_opis?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>29.08.-31.08.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="DogadjajiListSlika DogadjajiListSlika1 Zumiraj">
            <img src="/images/Dogadjaji/Dogadjaj08.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListNaslov">
            <h2><?=$tekst_dogadjaj8_naslov?></h2>
            <!--<p style="margin:5px 0;"><?=$tekst_dogadjaj8_opis?></p> -->
        </div>
        <div class="DogadjajiListDownload">
            <p>23.08.2014.-29.08.2014.</p>                    
            <img src="/images/DogadjajiLivo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please show your html too

Comment: I add it now, hope it hepls.

Comment: Have you tried using only floated divs without the ul-lists? Might work better for you.

Comment: Have you seen Bootstrap yet? I'm not saying you should include the whole library if you aren't using all the functionality. But looking at their methods for responsive design could help you out.

Comment: I try div put all they are different height so when I float them I don't get efect like in four list.

Comment: Not very familiar with bootstrap, only i use they datepicker plugin. I will give it a shot.